# The named parameter 'user' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument.dartmissing_required_argument

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al7ce.png)

//I'm getting this error called The named parameter 'user' is required, but there's no //corresponding argument. I'm developing a simple UI Facebook app using flutter, android //studio. didn't understand about the error I'm new to flutter. can anyone tell me what to do about this error?

```
import 'package:app_clone_ui/models/models.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Stories extends StatelessWidget {
  final User currentUser;
  final List<Story> stories;
  const Stories({
    Key? key,
    required this.currentUser,
    required this.stories,
  }):super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      color: Colors.purpleAccent,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1+stories.length,
        itemBuilder: (
          BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (index == 0){
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: _StoryCard(
// Code erro here MESSAGE (The named parameter 'story' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
// Try adding the required argument.)
                isAddStory: true,
                user: currentUser),
            );
          }
          final story = stories[index-1];
          return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
          child: _StoryCard(story: story),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class _StoryCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isAddStory;
  final User user;
  final Story story;
  const _StoryCard({
    Key? key,
      this.isAddStory = false,
      required this.user,
      required this.story,
  }):super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: isAddStory ? user.imageUrl : story.imageUrl,
          height: double.infinity,
          width: 110.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

your _storyCard required argument `user` and `story`.

```
  child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1+stories.length,
        itemBuilder: (
          BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (index == 0){
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: _StoryCard(
                story: stories[0] // add this line
                isAddStory: true,
                user: currentUser),
            );
          }
          final story = stories[index-1];
          return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
          child: _StoryCard(  
             story: story, 
             user: currentUser, // also this line.
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```